# Filter Dataframe based on column dictionary values

Tags: python, dataframe

The dataframe (`df`) contains a column with these values:

`column1`:

```
Sometext1
Sometext2
{‘a’: 1}
{‘b’: 2}
Sometext3
Sometext4
{‘c’: 3}
{‘d’: 4}
Sometext5
Sometext6
{‘e’: 5}
{‘f’: 6}
```

How can I select only the rows of `df` where say `column1` contains `dict` key: 'a' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the items that are formatted like a dictionary in your column still have a string data type.  Here is a solution using .apply():

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
print('BEFORE:\n', df)

target_key = 'a'
df[0] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[0][0] == '{' and x[0][2] == target_key else None, axis = 1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print('\nAFTER:\n', df)

#output:
BEFORE:
             0    1
0   Sometext1   aa
1   Sometext2   bb
2    {‘a’: 1}   vc
3    {‘b’: 2}   sd
4   Sometext3   we
5   Sometext4   df
6    {‘c’: 3}   fg
7    {‘d’: 4}   gh
8   Sometext5  asw
9   Sometext6   qw
10   {‘e’: 5}   fg
11   {‘f’: 6}   as

AFTER:
           0   1
2  {‘a’: 1}  vc
```

Comment: All the values of `column1` are `None` after running `df.apply(lambda x: ... )`

Comment: I tried it on your data as demonstrated above and it worked. There must be something peculiar about your dataframe. If you want help troubleshooting it, convert your dataframe to a dictionary using df.to_dict, print the dictionary and paste it above so I can work on it.

Comment: Sorry @pakpe for the late reply... I actually had problems with the encoding like e.g. `¬†` in `column1` and eventually managed to get it working with `lambda x: eval(x[0]).get(c)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do by iterating in element of your df and using With isinstance

```
for elem in df:
    if isinstance(elem, dict):
        if 'a' in elem.keys() :
            print (elem)
           #do whatever you Want with elem
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay @Renaud I tried using `for elem in df.iloc[:, i].tolist():` but `print (elem)` returns nothing :( ... Any idea why? The values appear to be strings `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: Do you know how to do this with `apply` or `applymap` and `lambda` expression? This way the entire DataFrame is updated based on the column values of `column1`, where the dictionary key matches the criteria